# Grouping Tasks in Conemu

Tags: conemu

I am sure in the past I have seen a setup of tasks in ConEmu, which allowed me to group tasks together under sub-menus, such as Cmd, Powershell etc.

I can't remember how to set this up and my google-fu has deserted me.

Answer (score 1):

Use double colon to name task groups. For example

```
Shell::cmd
Shell::PowerShell
Scripts::Jekyll build
```

Comment: Does this need a particular version of ConEmu as I have done that in my settings and it doesnt seem to be working.  [Settings screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/x89djzb6r/) [Tasks screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/4bowg6t4f/)

Comment: Of course yes. There is no reason to use old builds at all. cmder bundled with old ConEmu versions makes me crazy. What was auto-update feature created for?